# Flask endpoint vs Sagemaker endpoint

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask

I want to build a simple web app, where a person would enter some parameters of a car and my machine learning algorithm would predict the price of the car given the parameters. I want to learn aws and therefore want to deploy and host everything there.

By checking [websites](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-a-keras-deep-learning-model-as-a-web-application-in-p-fc0f2354a7ff) and [tutorials](https://machine-learning-company.nl/deploy-machine-learning-model-rest-api-using-aws/) I identified the following steps I need to do:

1. Collect data, train the model
2. Build Flask api around the pickled model to serve predictions
3. Create beautiful css/html front-end
4. Create a docker image
5. Push docker image to AWS ECR ad upload model artifact to S3
6. Creat Sagemaker prediction endpoint
7. Create an API endpoint with Chalice

What I don't understand is:

1. Why do I need to create a sagemaker endpoint (and Chalice endpoint) if I have already a flask endpoint that will predict the price? Cant I just spin-off the EC2 instance that will call flask endpoint and will give the prediction?
2. Are the steps I described the most efficient way to create a web app with ML model and deploy it to AWS?

Would be happy to learn about your opinion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are obviously many different architectures to achieve what you are trying to do.

Here is one that has worked for me in achieving something similar:

1) Set up AWS S3/RDS for data storage/collection etc - you can use S3 to store data for training as well as a place users can upload data from your web app. You can use RDS to store any metadata and keep track of all your items in your S3 bucket.

2) Use Elastic Beanstalk to host your web app. I've built a few Django apps (instead of Flask) and was able to easily integrate, deploy, etc. the apps with Elastic Beanstalk. Additionally, Elastic Beanstalk comes with a bunch of features that will help you easily manage traffic on your website.

3) Use Sagemaker to deploy your models. Once deployed, you can make pretty easy use of Amazon's SDK, Boto3, for sending data between your web app and your model for predictions.

The general idea is to split up the data, the web app, and the models into separate parts so that you can easily replace one part of your architecture with another if you find a better solution that fits.

Comment: Sounds good! However, I am still not sure why a sagemaker endpoint makes more sense than just a flask endpoint? Why should I create a sagemaker endpoint if it uses anyway the flask endpoint? Why cant' I just directly use flask endpoint?

Comment: The sagemaker endpoint comes with a lot of advantages like handling traffic and an SDK for connecting it to your web app. On the other hand, Sagemaker endpoints can be quite expensive depending on your instance. A Flask endpoint could work just as well - as long as you separate the prediction part of your app from the other web app functions you can easily try plugging and playing to see what works.

Comment: Cool, thank you! Regarding your last point about the separation of the prediction part and other web app functions, how do I do it exactly (I am not sure I understand it)? Do I create two applications: one flask web app for all functionalities except for the prediction and another flask web app for the prediction only? Or what do you mean by separation?

Comment: Exactly - if you use a Sagemaker endpoint, AWS has built the Boto3 SDK which will make this really easy - if you use your own Flask 'endpoint', you'll have to build the interaction between the two parts yourself which may not be too difficult.